# Add DropzoneJS for file upload with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I have a form with files uploading input that is working well but I want replace it with DropzoneJS to add drag and drop functionality but any files get uploaded with DropzoneJS.

This what my wiew looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing DropzoneJS with Laravel 5</title>


<script src="{{ asset('js/dropzone.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/dropzone.min.css') }}">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
            <form class="form-horizontal dropzone dz-clickable" action="{{url('/upload)}}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Name input-->

            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control">

            <div class="dz-message" id="my-dropzone">
            <h4>Drag Photos to Upload</h4>
            <span>Or click to browse</span>
            </div>

            <!-- Token -->
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
            <!-- Form actions -->

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add</button>
          </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my route file:

```
Route::post('/upload', function(){
    $the_new_product->name = Input::get('name');
    $the_new_product_picture = Input::file('file');

    return dd($the_new_product_picture); // I get Null as respons 
});
```

I get Null as respons, so I guess the file is not uploaded.
Am I missing something?

Comment: please post your javascript(with the dropjs implementation)

Comment: Well I guess I am missing something but I was following this tutorial http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/howto-ajax-multiple-file-upload-in-laravel/ and as far as I know, He didn't mention I have to use/add a JavaScript code/implementation :/

Comment: hmmm true, you really don't need to have any javascript code. Do you have any console errors? Try looking at the newtwork panel and see which parameters are posted

Comment: OK, I just check the network panel but only the text field name is posted and not the file field...

Comment: Could you check if when you drop a file, an input type="file" is injected into your form? Using the web inspector in chrome or firebug?

Comment: ok, I think this is a lil advanced for me, I don't know where to check this in Firebug :/

Comment: @FabioAntunes Hello, I've been trying to make this work but still no luck... I tried this code: https://paste.ee/p/rpIDK and if I drop a file (without clicking the submit button), I get this in the network panel: parameters https://paste.ee/p/UTPuJ . And If I click the submit button I get this https://paste.ee/p/kPKeV

Comment: If I manage to have some spare time I would try to implement dropJS today. Just for clarification which laravel you are using?

Comment: That would be awesome ... I am using Laravel 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I tried dropzone.js and it was was blazing fast and everything worked fine.

And after looking at your code, I think I figured out your problem:

On your **route.php** you have this:

```
Route::post('/upload', function(){
    $the_new_product->name = Input::get('name');
    $the_new_product_picture = Input::file('file');

    return dd($the_new_product_picture); // I get Null as respons 
});
```

This is wrong, you see when you want to fetch a file you must use **Request** not **Input**, Input was used on Laravel 4.2.

Just copy and paste this and overwrite your upload route on your **routes.php**

```
Route::post('/upload', function () {
    //check if file was uploaded
    if (Request::hasFile('file'))
    {
        //houston we have a file!
        $file = Request::file('file');

        //move it to our public folder and rename it to $name
        Request::file('file')->move('images', 'insert_file_name.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        echo 'file uploaded!';
        var_dump($file);
    }else{
        echo 'no file, no bueno';
    }
});
```

And that's it! If you want to read more about getting form inputs and files you should read the [Request documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) also since you usually want to validate that input, take a look at [Validation documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)

**EDIT:**
Here's my View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/dropzone.css') }}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/dropzone.js') }}"></script>

        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                color: #B0BEC5;
                display: table;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-family: 'Lato';
            }

            .container {
                text-align: center;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                 <form class="form-horizontal dropzone dz-clickable" action="{{url('/upload')}}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <!-- Name input-->

                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control">

                    <div class="dz-message" id="my-dropzone">
                    <h4>Drag Photos to Upload</h4>
                    <span>Or click to browse</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Token -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                    <!-- Form actions -->

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add</button>
                  </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, Thanks, Am testing your version, will let you know.

Comment: I just replaced the code and get a "no file, no bueno" meaning am still having the same problem :/ ... can you post your view file (the form)?

Comment: Well This is really really weird now... Still same result :/

Comment: Well check your laravel logs, maybe you have some error there, you can find your logs under `storage\logs\laravel-2015-06-DAY.log`

Comment: Still same problem, one thing I notice though while inspecting in the browser is that once I drop a file, all input are posted (via Ajax???) but when hit the submit button only the name input and the token are posted. And that log file show this: `#33 {main}  
[2015-06-13 22:41:22] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function move() on a non-object' in C:\Bitnami\nginxstack-1.6.2-1\nginx\html\L5\app\Http\routes.php:328
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  `

Comment: you are right, I just checked again and dropzone submits your files via ajax, you can't submit files and other html input. If you check your public folder you must have a file that was uploaded via ajax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80492/discussion-between-asme-just-and-fabio-antunes).