# Laravel Dropzone with product info

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for solution to use dropzoneJs in laravel 5.5 while writing my products.

What I want to do is: upload my images and fill my product info then save all together just like WordPress/Joomla etc.

[image: wordpress sample]

What do I have so far:

`Images Table`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('images', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
    }
```

My form in Products `create.blade.php`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'image-upload' ]) !!}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <h4 style="text-align: center;color:#428bca;">Drop images in this area  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-down"></span></h4>
            <!-- Input code below Not working yet -->
            <input type="text" name="product_id" value="" hidden>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
<!-- drozone -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.options.imageUpload = {
      maxFilesize: 5, //MB
      acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif"
  };
</script>
```

My `ImageController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Image;
use App\Product;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
  public function dropzone()
  {
      return view('dropzone-view');
  }

  public function dropzoneStore(Request $request)
  {
      $image = $request->file('file');
      $imageName = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);
      return response()->json(['success'=>$imageName]);
  }
}
```

And my routes:

```
Route::get('dropzone', 'ImageController@dropzone');
  Route::post('dropzone/store', ['as'=>'dropzone.store','uses'=>'ImageController@dropzoneStore']);
```

Any Idea On That?

Comment: You done need a form to upload using dropzone. Have all look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806424/add-dropzonejs-for-file-upload-with-laravel-5

Comment: @usrNotFound Hi, i tried that in my controller i got `[object Object]` error and where do i get my product id to relate these photos into it? i'm not see anything about that in function.

Comment: you have to pass product id as a part of post variable or maybe in a route. so your route will be `product/{id}/dropzone/store` or whatever you want. Then you can find product in you controller using id

Comment: @usrNotFound https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159102/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-mafortis Please